# Function on the unit circle and exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Let $\mathbb{S}^1 := \{z\in \mathbb C, |z|=1 \}$ and $f : \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$, continuous.

Is it always true that there exists a continuous function $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $\forall t\in \mathbb R$, $f(e^{it}) =e^{ig(t)}$ ?

If no, do you an example, if yes a proof ?

I know that if I replace "continuous" by "continuously differentiable" then the result is true, but the proof does not seem to extend easily with reduced assumptions.

Comment: 1.  That probably should say unit circle instead of unit sphere, shouldn't it?  2.  Are you wondering whether the assertion is true with "continuous" instead of "continuously differentiable", or are you saying it's true and you're wondering how to show it?

Comment: 1. I changed to circle. 2."Is it always true...."

Comment: It's true, and for many proofs the proof works without serious modifications. What proof do you know for the continuously differentiable case? If you know a bit of covering theory from topology, it also drops directly out of that.

Answer (score 0):

For example $$g(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\pi-t, t\in [0,\pi)\\ 
3\pi-t, t\in [\pi, 2\pi)
\end{matrix}\right.$$
is not continuous in $t_0=\pi$. But $f(e^{it})=e^{ig(t)}$ is continuous on $S^1$.

[image]

Generally, we could obvioulsy avoid things like $$f(e^{it})=f(e^{i(t + 2k\pi)})$$
by limiting $t \in [0, 2\pi)$.

And, generally, define $g$ in such a way that for any $z \in S^1$, $z=e^{it} \overset{f}{\rightarrow} e^{iy}$ or $g(t)=y$, thus $f(e^{it})=e^{iy}=e^{ig(t)}$.

Obviously, we could avoid annomalies like $$g(t)=y+2k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}$$ because this isn't a function.

With these restrictions we can prove $g$ is a function if $f$ is a function, i.e. for $t$, $g(t)$ is unique. Because $f$ is a function then for $e^{iy_1} \ne e^{iy_2} \Rightarrow e^{it_1} \ne e^{it_2}$ where $f(e^{it_1})=e^{iy_1}$ and $f(e^{it_2})=e^{iy_2}$. Given the $[0,2\pi)$ boundary we set, this means $g(t_1)=y_1 \ne y_2=g(t_2) \Rightarrow t_1 \ne t_2 $.

However is $g(t)$ generally continuous, given $f(z)$ is?

From $|e^{it_0}-e^{it}| < \sigma \Rightarrow |e^{iy_0}-e^{iy}| < \epsilon$ we have 
$$\sqrt{(\cos{t_0}-\cos{t})^2+(\sin{t_0}-\sin{t})^2} < \sigma \Rightarrow \sqrt{(\cos{y_0}-\cos{y})^2+(\sin{y_0}-\sin{y})^2} < \epsilon$$
or
$$\sqrt{2-2(\cos{t_0}\cos{t}+\sin{t_0}\sin{t})} < \sigma \Rightarrow \sqrt{2-2(\cos{y_0}\cos{y}+\sin{y_0}\sin{y})} < \epsilon$$
or
$$\sqrt{2-2\cos{(t_0-t})} < \sigma \Rightarrow \sqrt{2-2\cos{(y_0-y})} < \epsilon$$
And here comes the trouble when 
$$t_0-t \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow y_0-y \rightarrow 2\pi$$

P.S. I am sorry for the drawing quality ...

Comment: That a continuous $f$ also has discontinuous lifts is not a problem. The question is whether it also always has continuous lifts, and that it has.

Comment: The example on top is a flip around imaginary axis, can it be replaced with another version $g$  which is continuous?

Comment: Just take $g(t) = \pi - t$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Right, so that basically accommodates the image to make $g$ continuous.